# How do i impliment pagination here (only for the next pages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would i implement pagination in this case.. I am using a gem that already calculate the next pages. `@client.videos_by(:tags=>{:include=>[:cover,:acoustic]},:page=>2)` (page is method from the gem that accept page number) This query returns array of videos in the second page only, if i substitute with 3 it is going to return the third page only.How do i implement the next page? This is what i tried but when i click next it keeps returning the first page every single time.

**Controller**

```
   class StarsController < ApplicationController
     @@current||=1
      def index
       @videos=@client.videos_by(:tags=>{:include=>[:cover,:acoustic]},:page=>@@current)
      end

       def next
          @@current+=1
           redirect_to :action=>'index'
       end
      end
```

**View**

```
     <%= link_to "next",:controller=>"stars",:action=>"next" %>
```

Comment: Which gem are you using for pagination?

Comment: I am not using any gem for pagination but i am using youtube_it https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/blob/master/lib/youtube_it/response/video_search.rb gem which impliment simple pagination from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class variable (`@@current`) is a bad idea because it is shared among all users.
You can simply use a parameter with the `index` method:

```
class StarsController < ApplicationController     
  def index
    @page = params[:page] || 1 
    @videos = @client.videos_by(:tags=>{:include=>[:cover,:acoustic]},:page=> @page)
  end
end
```

In the view

```
 <%= link_to "next", :action=>"index", :page => @page + 1 %>
```

Comment: Thank you Baldrick i will try this, and will let you know.